# Is it possible to translate a Revit file to a format where I could retrieve geometries (XY points/positions and shapes)?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-model-derivative

I have a Revit file that I would like to extract shapes and geometry data from. Is this possible with Autodesk Forge Model Derivative API? 
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It really depends on your context and needs.

- If you wish to work online in the web → use Forge
- If you wish to avoid installing Revit on a desktop computer (or at all) → use Forge
- If you wish to execute Revit as an unattended server app → use Forge

Otherwise, you can also install Revit on a Windows desktop and use the Revit .NET API to extract shapes and geometry data.

In the Forge scenario, you can either use the Model Derivative API, as you and Petr suggested and discussed, or you can implement your own geometry extraction code using the Revit API and execute that in the Forge context using the Forge Design Automation API. The actual Revit API code code is similar in both environments. For Design Automation, you wrap your .NET add-in code into a work item uploaded to and executed by Forge.

The Building Coder shares some comparisons between desktop and Design Automation coding in the topic group on working with [DA4R, or Design Automation for Revit](https://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/about-the-author.html#5.55.)

Answer (score 0):

The Model Derivative service converts your designs into a proprietary file format - optimized for viewing on the web using Forge Viewer - called *SVF*. The format isn't publicly documented but there's a Node.js library that can be used to parse SVF assets, and potentially output them into glTF which would be easier to analyze: https://github.com/petrbroz/forge-convert-utils.